# Google cloud deploy static app from bucket without using local machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, gsutil

I have an auto build pipe line in google cloud build :

```
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil"
  entrypoint: gsutil
  args: ["-m","rsync","-r","gs://my-bucket-main","gs://my-bucket-destination"]
```

I gave the following permissions to

```
xxxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com

Cloud Build Service Account
Cloud Functions Developer
Service Account User
Storage Admin
Storage Object Admin
```

But I get :
Caught non-retryable exception while listing gs://my-bucket-destination/: AccessDeniedException: 403 xxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Even if I add permission owner to xxxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com I get the same error. I do not understand how it is possible that Storage Admin and Storage Object Admin does not provide storage.object.list access!

Even when I am doing that in my local machine where gcloud is pointed to the project and I use `gsutil -m rsync -r gs://my-bucket-main gs://my-bucket-destination` still I get :

```
Caught non-retryable exception while listing gs://my-bucket-destination/: AccessDeniedException: 403 XXXXX@YYYY.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

XXXXX@YYYY.com account is the owner and I also gave "Storage Admin" and
"Storage Object Admin" access to it too

any idea?

Comment: The error message tells you the cloud build service account does not have permission. Now you need to figure out why it does not have permission when you think it does. 1) Go to the Google Cloud GUI and double-check that you have added the correct roles to the correct service account in the correct project. 2) Double-check that you have not misspelled the bucket name. If you specify a bucket that is not part of your project (owned by another project), you will get that permission error.

Comment: Hello John, Thanks but I wrote in the above texts that I gave all the permission and obviously to the current project that I am working. I have no clue why it is not working. Even with my machine as the owner, by running the above code I get the same error. Beside to be owner I added 
Storage Admin
Storage Object Admin to my account but still the same error shows up

Answer (score 2):

The service account is creating that error. My suggestion is to set the correct IAM roles of your service account on a bucket-level.

There are two approaches to set permission of the service account on the two buckets:

**1. Using Google Cloud Console:**

- Go to the Cloud Storage [Browser](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser) page.
- Click the **Bucket overflow menu** on the far right of the row associated with the bucket.
- Choose **Edit bucket permissions**.
- Click **+Add members** button.
- In the New members field, enter one or more identities that need access to your bucket.
- Select a role (or roles) from the **Select a role** drop-down menu. The roles you select appear in the pane with a short description of the permissions they grant. You can choose **Storage Admin** role for full control of the bucket.
- Click **Save**.

**2. Using gsutil command:**

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:xxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com:objectAdmin gs://my-bucket-main

gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:xxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com:objectAdmin gs://my-bucket-destination
```

---

For full **gsutil command** documentation, You may refer here: [Using IAM with buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#gsutil)